# How to show $d_{\mathsf{CE}}$ induces a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra and $d_{\mathsf{CE}}: \Lambda^k \mathfrak{g}^*\longrightarrow \Lambda^{k+1} \mathfrak{g}^*$ be the Chevalley-Eilenberg differential given by:

$$d_{\mathsf{CE}} \varepsilon(x_1, \ldots, x_{k+1})=\sum_{i<j} \varepsilon([x_i, x_j], x_1, \ldots, \widehat{x_i}, \ldots, \widehat{x_j}, \ldots, x_{k+1}).$$

Recall, that for any vector spaces $E$ and $F$ with $F$ finite dimensional $$\mathsf{Hom}(E, F)\longrightarrow \mathsf{Hom}(F^*, E^*), f\longmapsto f^*,$$ where $f^*$ is the transpose of $f$, is a linear isomorphism.

Since $d_{\mathsf{CE}}\in \mathsf{Hom}(\mathfrak{g}^*, \Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g}^*)$ it induces a map which lives in $\mathsf{Hom}(\Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g})$. How to show this induced map is a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$? Is there any reference where I can find this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you mean. If you specialize the formula for $d_{CE}$ (which by the way misses a factor $(-1)^{i+j}$) to the case $k=1$, then you get $(d_{CE}\epsilon)(X,Y)=-\epsilon([X,Y])$. This says that $d_{CE}$ in degree one is dual to the given Lie bracket on $\mathfrak g$.

Maybe you actually mean that whether a general differential on $\Lambda^*\mathfrak g^*$ defines a Lie bracket via the dual of the degree-one component. I think this is true, too, since the fact that $d_{CE}\circ d_{CE}=0$ speicialized to degree one exactly says that the dual satisfies the Jacobi identity.